# A doubt on the definition of orthogonal complement

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, orthogonality

For a subset $M$ of a inner-product space $V$, the orthogonal complement $M^{\bot}$ is defined as $$M^{\bot} =\{x\in V\mid \langle x, v\rangle = 0\mbox{ for all } v\in M\}.$$
My question is: why we have to take all $x\in V$? It makes no sense take, for example, $x\in V\setminus{M}$?

I am sorry if my question is "stupid", but it id just a curiosity.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you take $x \in V \backslash M$, you exclude the zero vector, which is included in $M$ if $M$ is a subspace of $V$, which it usually is in this context.

Comment: Not only is zero excluded but $V \setminus M$ will also include vectors not orthogonal to $M$.  May I suggest you look at a few simple $2$-dimensional examples to get a feel for the orthogonal complement and how it compares to $V \setminus M$.

Comment: @WADon could you help me with an example?

Comment: For a simple example, consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, equipped with the usual inner product. Choose a simple subspace $M = \text{span}\{(1,0)\}$. This is the $y=0$ line. The orthogonal complement is given by $\text{span}\{(0,1)\}$. This is the $x=0$ line, not the whole space take away $M$.